# php based Neural Network — how to implement backpropagation

Tags: php

nothing is ever simple for `bacpropagation` with php? or examples of the case of solving problem `XOR`? whether you want to share?

I've created, `XOR`, too, just not maximized.  this, declaration variable type double in the php there is do not rules?? because i have a problem when the variable whose value `-5.92878775009E-323` multiplied by `(*) 0.00310811260635` is `0`;

I tried in excel too, error / zero, meaning the problem is of variable length that I specify, while the variable I declared value `"null"` as `"public w = null"`. sorry a lot of questions ..

thanks if you want to answer my questions..

Comment: This is either too advanced for me, or it's not well written. Can you try to clarify what you are trying to do? Also you should really have only one question per question.

Comment: Well, if you multiply something that is E-323 and E-4 this is rounded to 0, maybe you need some better precision.

Comment: I think you need an analogue computer; or perhaps a 128-bit version of PHP

Comment: Have you tried increasing the jigawatts to 1.21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-5.92878775009E-323 is such a ridiculously small number that it will compute as zero.  The best way to handle this is to use standard exponent mathematics.

I would handle this by multiplying the digits then summing the exponents in a custom function.  That having been said, if you need to manage these numbers, you are probably already losing a lot of information in the rounding to 12 significant figures.

If you need to do this without loss of data, the only way I can think of doing it is to use the computer to do the multiplication much in the same way it is handled on paper, one digit at a time.

Why not write a function like this?

Alternatively, if you are not feeling suicidal, try [bcmul()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php) which is a PHP function that does exactly what you need.

Comment: ok guys I'm sorry, I want to make a financial forecasting applications, these applications implement the backpropagation algorithm. in this case I am using XOR as an example. I want to find the best weight on the input, bias, output. and I have done. but when at umpteenth iteration, I find that the multiplication of the weights on hidden-output and bias weighting produce 0. value of hidden-output weights =-5.92878775009E-323 and the weight bias = 0.00310811260635. is type of data problem? because I declared null, as the "public $w = null". i need help. tx 4 all answer..